# Next steps around my first question: edit, bounty, posting a follow-up question or something else

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, new-users

My first question in the the main site is [Is "citizen development" <software development> an old thing with new name in the project management field?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/q/34497/25847). It was a "hot question", got >2k views so far, got two answers from others that I appreacite but they look to be biased to a sentiment against a common software vendors sell speach idea:

> Low code / no code platforms enable anyone to create apps

I think that this occurred in part because the use of `"citizen development" <software developement>` in the title similar to what is done Wikipedia (they use round instead of angle brackets). My intention was say that `citizen development` in my questions refers to a specific usage of others found when searching about it, i.e. Google Books returned results from several subjects:

**Related to people creating apps for themselves and others**

- Citizen Development: The Handbook for Creators and Change Makers
- Intelligent Automation Simplified: Learn Enterprise Automation, AI-Led Automation, and Robotic Process Automation with Use-cases

**Related to inhabitants of a city, nation or commonwealth**

- Citizenship today : global perspectives and practices
- Citizen Education Today -- Developing Civil Competencies
- The concept of constituency political representation, democratic legitimacy, and institutional design

I think that to get attention again to the question but this time no so biased to the usage of `citizen development` by low code / no code vendors, I could

- Edit the question

  - I know that this should be done in such way that do not invalidate current answers.
- Keep the question as is and offer a bounty

  - As my reputation is relative slow I'm worry to sacrifice the privileges and not getting the attention that I'm looking for.
- Post a new question

  - This might be the easier option but I not sure that it is the more convenient next step as the attention might be dispersed instead of focused
- Something else?

What do you suggest?

Comment: Hi Ruben - what makes you think that removing the "citizen development" would change the overall results from your question? There's already two answers stating pretty much the same. Besides, how clarifying this concept will help you? The lingo in IT is oftentimes context / environment dependent, so even if there could be a canonical answer for "is low code a new or old idea", the value of it would be marginal... unless you'd be using this to support any argument beyond the question (i.e. for a new project proposal, for instance).

Comment: @TiagoCardoso I'm sorry if I give the idea that I'm considering to remove "citizen development", I'm not considering that as the core of the question is to understand that term. How about posting a follow-up question with the following title: How is "citizen development" different from "end-user development" from the perspective of a project management office?

Comment: Seems like a pretty razonable question from my perspective, although the lingo part of IT is always lacking single sources of truth... so your mileage my vary (by a lot).